# How to get the BILUO tags of a token in spaCy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Currently, in spaCy, it's possible to get the IOB tags of a token using the `ent_iob_` attribute ([docs](https://spacy.io/docs/api/token#attributes)). e.g.:

```
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en')
>>> doc = nlp(u'My name is George Washington Singer, and I am an Englishman')
>>> [i.ent_iob_ for i in doc]
[u'O', u'O', u'O', u'B', u'I', u'I', u'O', u'O', u'O', u'O', u'O', u'B']
```

However, when training a model, spacy takes BILUO ([docs](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/entity-recognition#updating)). Is there a way to convert the readily available IOB tags to BILUO, or get the BILUO tags directly?

Spacy version 1.8

Answer (score 6):

To convert IOB to BILUO, spacy.gold has a `iob_to_biluo` function.

```
>>> import spacy
>>> from spacy.gold import iob_to_biluo
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en')
>>> doc = nlp(u'My name is George Washington Singer, and I am an Englishman')
>>> iobs = [i.ent_iob_ for i in doc]
>>> iob_to_biluo(iobs)
[u'O', u'O', u'O', u'B-', u'I-', u'L-', u'O', u'O', u'O', u'O', u'O', u'U-']
```

Tested on spaCy version '2.1.3'

The source can be found [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/gold.pyx#L179).

Comment: I'm getting this error ValueError: [E177] Ill-formed IOB input detected: B

Answer (score 1):

Extending LukeG's answer, if you prefer to get the full tokens (e.g. `O`, `U-PER`, `B-ORG`, `I-ORG`), this should work (tested with spaCy 3.0.5).

```py
import spacy
from spacy.training import iob_to_biluo # this used to be in spacy.gold, changed in ver 3

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
doc = nlp("Germany is a country in Europe")
iob =  [f"{token.ent_iob_}-{token.ent_type_}" if token.ent_iob_ != "O" else "O" for token in doc]
biluo = iob_to_biluo(iob)
print(biluo)
```

results:

```
['U-GPE', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'U-LOC']
```

Couldn't find any way other than concatentaing the iob prefix and the entity type.